# Removing a wordpress multisite installation and preserving the database before migrate to nginx

Tags: multisite, mysql, wp-cli

I have a WordPress multisite installation, and I need to remove the multisite, and keeps just the site ID 5 (domain.com/br) in the main address (domain.com).

So I follow this tutorial to remove WordPress multisite installation: http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/uninstall-multisite/. After that I dropped `wp` tables `post`, `terms`, `term_taxonomy` etc, and changed the tables `wp_5_` to `wp_`. My site became extremely slow to open pages, his aesthetic was greatly affected, images did not load, so I was informed about the serialized data in the database, and that I should not change the database manually.

I do not intend to migrate the multisite to NGINX, so I think I have 2 options:

Do a stand alone installation (domain.com/br in domain.com, and after redirect .com to .com/br), and stay with a single website.
change the database tables from site ID 5 to the main site tables database (I mean keeps just one database working perfectly), and migrate a single website.

Which do you recommend, and can you provide references on how to do this?

p.s.: I'm disregarding the option of buying a plugin to do this, and learning to do at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a couple of things. WordPress has a built-in Importer/Exporter you can find under the Tools menu:

[image: WordPress Admin "Tools" menu showing Import and Export features]

The tool is a bit hit or miss, your mileage may vary.

Alternatively, you can do the following:

***First**, take backups of everything!!*

It sounds like you already have, but do it again, just in case.

1. Export *only* the `wp_5_` tables from your current database to a SQL file.
2. Next, create a fresh new WordPress single site. Don't add any content or anything, just set it up.
3. Import the SQL file from step `1.` into your single site database. Now, you should have both `wp_` and `wp_5_` tables.
4. You have a couple of options now:

   - In your `wp-config.php`, change this line `$table_prefix = 'wp_';` to `$table_prefix = 'wp_5_';`
   - OR: Run a query like this for EVERY table you want to migrate:

```sql
INSERT INTO wp_posts SELECT * FROM wp_5_posts;
-- ... etc, so for terms you would do
INSERT INTO wp_terms SELECT * FROM wp_5_terms;
```

Comment: *In your wp-config.php, change this line $table_prefix = 'wp_'; to $table_prefix = 'wp_5_';*


In this case, I need some tables from 'wp_', like users.

*OR: Run a query like this for EVERY table you want to migrate:*

And about the images?

I do not know in which folder I should export the images, and I do not know if I should do this with a predefined rule, for example, if the images are organized according to the upload date of them.

Comment: @paivadaniel On the `$table_prefix` part, you are correct that you would need to rename `wp_users` and `wp_usermeta`, which kind of defats the point (although it's only _two_ renames). The `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` will not touch serialization at all. **Images**: I can't help much there, unfortunately. It depends on what your image paths look like, but all of the site's images you're migrating are in `wp-content/uploads/site/5/` (I believe, or something similar). You _may_ be able to copy the images from `/5/` to `wp-content/uploads`, but I'm not sure that will work.

Answer (score 0):

> In your wp-config.php, change this line $table_prefix = 'wp_'; to $table_prefix = 'wp_5_';

In this case, I need some tables from 'wp_', like users. So, what do you suggest? For example, create new 'wp_5_' tables to users, and them migrate the database with the second option that you gave me. I think this should work.

> OR: Run a query like this for EVERY table you want to migrate:
>   INSERT INTO wp_posts SELECT * FROM wp_5_posts;

Will not I have problems with date serialization doing this?

I know that the wp search-replace command does not generate this kind of problem, I was thinking of using it for this.

**And about the images?**

I do not know in which folder of wp-content I should export the images, and I do not know if I should do this with a predefined rule, for example, if the images are organized according to the upload date of them.